# Defining Idempotence

Tags: web-services, http, rest, http-verbs, idempotent

So "idempotence" can be defined as:

An action, that if performed N times has the same effect as performing the action only once.

Got it, easy enough.

My question is about the subtlety of this definition -is an action considered idempotent by itself, or must you also consider the data being passed into the action?

Let me clarify with an example:

Suppose I have a PUT method that updates some resource, we'll call it `f(x)`

Obviously, `f(3)` is idempotent, as long as I supply 3 as the input. And equally obvious, `f(5)` will change the value of the resource (i.e., it will no longer be 3 or whatever value was there previously)

So when we talk about idempotence, are we referring to the generalization of the action/function like (i.e., `f(x)`), or are we referring to action/function + the data being passed into it (i.e., `f(3)`)?

Comment: Should this not be moved to the Mathematics forum? (For all clarity: I did not downvote)

Comment: Depends if we're talking about a definition in formal logic, or a definition in web programming. I suspect the downvoter (not me) just thought the question was ill-posed.

Comment: @Roy -I don't think so, since it applies directly to RESTful web services, and that is the context I wrote the example in

Comment: I think it's valid to discuss here, as there are definite CS applications, discussed midway down the page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence

Comment: it may be useful for someone looking to understand the concept: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/fp-concepts/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Suppose I have a PUT method that updates some resource, we'll call it
>   f(x)
>
> Obviously, f(3) is idempotent, as long as I supply 3 as the input. And
>   equally obvious, f(5) will change the value of the resource (i.e., it
>   will no longer be 3 or whatever value was there previously).

This is only obvious is the server implementation is such that `PUT` respects this idempotent property. In the context of HTTP, [RFC 2616 says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2):

> Methods can also have the property of "idempotence" in that (aside
>   from error or expiration issues) the side-effects of N > 0 **identical**
>   requests is the same as for a single request.

Going a bit off topic...
In a distributed system like the web, you may also want to consider commutativity and concurrent requests. For example N+1 of the same PUT(x1) request should have the same effect, but you don't know if another client made a different PUT(x2) request in between yours, so while n*PUT(x1)=PUT(x1) and m*PUT(x2)=PUT(x2), the two sets of requests could be interleaved.

Comment: So from this we can conclude, in this example, PUT is idempotent in the context of a single request. But even when it is interleaved with other concurrent requests it is still idempotent as the first operation's result followed the idempotence property, isn't it.

Answer (score 5):

Idempotence requires that the action holds for all values over its domain, i.e., `f(f(x)) = f(x)` for all `x`. Another way to think about it is that an operation is idempotent if the composition of the operation with itself is just that operation.

Comment: @JonathanM Sorry, I don't see your point. `abs(abs(x)) = abs(x)` for all `x`, over the reals or the complex numbers. If you think `abs` doesn't match what I stated, please give a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

You're assuming idempotence means that the state of the server will be changed *at most once* by a series of invocations. Most of the time, people use this term to mean that the state on the server *won't be changed at all* by any number of invocations. Under these circumstances, the distinction between your two cases is immaterial.

Comment: But state that "won't be changed at all" is "nullipotent", right? This would be GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, and TRACE

Answer (score 3):

This is not quite the definition of idempotence. A function is idempotent if for any item x, f(f(x)) == f(x).

PUT is a side effect of your f() function here, not the result of it.

Comment: Your definition goes against that given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence. The page first sites `abs()` as an idempotent function, but it would not be by your definition.

Comment: This is simply wrong. You've defined idempotence to be equivalent to the identity function. You're implicitly assuming that the operation has already been done to x.

Comment: I suspect you could clarify your answer a bit without much trouble; relating idempotence specifically to the PUT operations would be useful.

Comment: If I understand correctly, every identity function is idempotent, but the opposite isn't true.