# What is idempotency in HTTP methods?

Tags: http

I've read HTTP documentation, but I can't understand what is *idempotency*. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you asking what "idempotent" means, or are you asking why the "idempotent" verbs are are useful?

Comment: See ***[The Two Generals' Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP-rGJKSZ3s&t=415s)*** for an excellent video explanation for why *idempotency* is useful.

Comment: Nice link reference, but it drops you right in the middle the sponsored advert. Coincidence? :)

Answer (score 197, accepted):

> What is idempotency in HTTP methods?

*Idempotency* is a property of HTTP methods.

A request method is considered *idempotent* if the intended *effect* on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the *effect* for a single such request. And it's worthwhile to mention that idempotency is about the *effect* produced on *the state of the resource* on the server and not about the *response status code* received by the client.

To illustrate this, consider the `DELETE` method, which is defined as idempotent. Now consider a client performs a `DELETE` request to delete a resource from the server. The server processes the request, the resource gets deleted and the server returns `204`. Then the client repeats the same `DELETE` request and, as the resource has already been deleted, the server returns `404`.

Despite the different status code received by the client, the effect produced by a single `DELETE` request is the same effect of multiple `DELETE` requests to the same URI.

Finally, requests with idempotent methods can be repeated automatically if a communication failure occurs before the client is able to read the server's response. The client knows that repeating the request will have the *same intended effect*, even if the original request succeeded, though the response might be different.

### RFC 7231

Let's have a look at the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the document defines the semantics and the content of the HTTP/1.1 protocol. See the quotes below (highlights are mine).

HTTP methods can be **safe**:

> [**4.2.1.  Safe Methods**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)
>
> **Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only**; i.e., the client does not request, and does not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of applying a safe method to a target resource. [...]
>
> This definition of safe methods does not prevent an implementation from including behavior that is potentially harmful, that is not entirely read-only, or that causes side effects while invoking a safe method.  What is important, however, is that the client did not request that additional behavior and cannot be held accountable for it. [...]
>
> Of the request methods defined by this specification, the `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, and `TRACE` methods are defined to be safe. [...]

And/or **idempotent**:

> [**4.2.2.  Idempotent Methods**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2)
>
> **A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the effect for a single such request**.  Of the request methods defined by this specification, `PUT`, `DELETE`, and safe request methods are idempotent. [...]
>
> Like the definition of safe, the idempotent property only applies to what has been requested by the user; a server is free to log each request separately, retain a revision control history, or implement other non-idempotent side effects for each idempotent request. [...]

Summarizing, the HTTP methods are classified as [following](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.1.3):

```
+---------+------+------------+
| Method  | Safe | Idempotent |
+---------+------+------------+
| CONNECT | no   | no         |
| DELETE  | no   | yes        |
| GET     | yes  | yes        |
| HEAD    | yes  | yes        |
| OPTIONS | yes  | yes        |
| POST    | no   | no         |
| PUT     | no   | yes        |
| TRACE   | yes  | yes        |
+---------+------+------------+
```

### RFC 5789

The [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) defines the [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) method, which is *neither safe nor idempotent*. However, to prevent collisions, [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) requests can be issued such a way as to be idempotent, as quoted below:

> A `PATCH` request can be issued in such a way as to be idempotent, which also helps prevent bad outcomes from collisions between two `PATCH` requests on the same resource in a similar time frame. Collisions from multiple `PATCH` requests may be more dangerous than `PUT` collisions because some patch formats need to operate from a known base-point or else they will corrupt the resource.  Clients using this kind of patch application SHOULD use a conditional request such that the request will fail if the resource has been updated since the client last accessed the resource.  For example, the client can use a strong `ETag` in an `If-Match` header on the `PATCH` request.

Comment: How is `DELETE` an idempotent method? Which if successful would normally return a `200 (OK)` or `204 (No Content)`.

Comment: @NisargPatil Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4088350/1426227).

Comment: Answer in above question was self-explanatory. Thanks :)

Comment: `TRACE` is not always Safe method, it can change origin's state.

Comment: REST tutorials state that the resource should be updated using `PUT` instead of `POST` because `PUT` is idempotent. "if the `PUT` request fails, we may simply resend it until we get a successful response from the server". What prevents me from re-sending a failed `POST` request (with the update) ? Something wrong will happen ?

Comment: @mangusta I treat POSTs as idempotent following that same mindset you mentioned (as does Square, Stripe and others).  I'd argue it falls in the definition, trying to change nothing to the same something through multiple same requests (due to failed comms or whatever) to achieve the same affect (add that 1 thing). Using the idempotency_key feels more effective than dupe request checking or handling the fallout from batches of "failed" POSTs.

Comment: @C.J. I see. I thought there might be some functionality-related reason (built into the HTTP itself) of why PUT can be resent without worries while POST cannot. Now it appears that we are simply required to conform to the HTTP standards and the behaviour is totally based on how the server is implemented

Comment: In other words it is just a convention rather than the http feature

Answer (score 10):

In my understanding, idempotency has nothing to do with the result (=Server Response), but with the server-state after one or multiple calls.

Let's say you want to delete a resource on the server by calling

```
DELETE /resource/123
```

The call *may* return with a HTTP-Response `200 OK` and the deleted resource as payload in the first place. In a second call, the Response will be `204 NO_CONTENT` as the resource has already been deleted by the first call.

After each request the server-state is the same, therefore idempotency is fulfilled. The HTTP/1.1 says nothing about the response

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on
>      the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the
>      same as the effect for a single such request

Comment: Nit: 204 No Content is not really a good response code to indicate that a resource has been deleted.

Comment: @Evert - why do you say that ?

Comment: @MasterJoe I'm taking this back a little. I think now a recommendation is that it's OK for multiple idempotent requests to return the same status, even if only the first one actually deleted the resource. `204` is sometimes confused to mean: 'This resource is deleted', which is probably why I mentioned this ... but my comment was wrong.

Comment: I believe you have the correct distinction in the first part of your answer, in that it is regarding *state*. I think of this as the effect on the data/database rather than the server, but you could say "server-state". If you submit multiple idempotent requests to a server, subsequent requests may bog down the server and send different responses, but the DATA will only be changed the first time.

Answer (score -1):

**TLDR**

> Idempotenc : **GET, PUT** : WHY ?

- **GET** If fired recursively **exact** `/resource/123` it will give **same** result
- **PUT** If fired recursively **exact** `/user/123` it will give **same** result

> NON Idempotence :**DELETE ,POST** : WHY ?

- **DELETE** If fired recursively **exact** `/user/123` it will give **different** result second time(404 or NOT_FOUND)
- **POST** If fired recursively **exact** `/user/(id is assigned by server)` it will give **different** result every-time

**Conclusion** : **DELETE** is Idempotenc by http docs ,  but its behaviour is Non-idempotence

if request gives same result

for exact same url fired recursly

Comment: DELETE is defined to be idempotent.

Comment: @JulianReschke "DELETE is defined to be idempotent. ?  YES" but its behaviour is NON IDEMPOTENT

Comment: Yes, it is idempotent. "A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the effect for a single such request." That is the case for DELETE. Status codes are irrelevant, the state of the resource is.

Comment: @JulianReschke  In DELETE rest api `/user/123`, 1st Time it returns(200 OR success) BUT during second time it SHOULD return (404 OR NOT_FOUND).From api point of view its Emitting Different OUTPUT(1st 202 && 2nd 404) .Though on server its not updating anything but its emitting different Result for same http request,What About That ?

Comment: That's fine. What's relevant is that after the request, the resource is gone.

Comment: @vijay I don't think being Idempotent is about "what result is given". Instead it is about the state or origin/server.

Comment: @vijay have you edited the answer ( few updates given by Julian ) because not sure whether your answer modified or not .

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand , can u see edit history of this answer?

Comment: @vijay thanks, could not notified the history sorry   . thanks for your time :) happy coding

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52457399/revisions

Comment: @JulianReschke - So I think that the answer is incorrect now. Should we return 204 every time or return 200 1st time & 204 after that ? By your given definition of idempotence, 200 + 404 or 200 + 204 should be considered as having same effect on a server, even though the response of the server is different. I have typically seen returning only 204. Do a get to see if you have 404. 200 + 404 seems like deviant design to me.

Comment: In the context of idempotency, the status code doesn't matter. The resulting server state does.

Comment: What matters is the state of the backend, even if the response is 2XX the first time and the second time a 404, the state of the backend is the same after both calls. That makes it idempotent.

Comment: This answer is wrong - "DELETE is Idempotenc by http docs , but its behaviour is Non-idempotence" - this is wrong as there is no such thing as "behavior (non)idempotence". Idempotent operations is one for which S(S(X)) = S(X) for every X (where X is init state and S(X) state after operation). DELETE(DELETE(X)) = DELETE(X), hence DELETE is idempotent. It's idempotent according to definition in HTTP RFCs, in math, in computer science and any other I could find

Answer (score -3):

An idempotent HTTP method is an HTTP method that can be called many times without different outcomes. It would not matter if the method is called only once, or ten times over. The result should be the same. It essentially means that the result of a successfully performed request is independent of the number of times it is executed. For example, in arithmetic, adding zero to a number is idempotent operation.

POST is NOT idempotent.
GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS and TRACE are idempotent.

1>POST -->Every time you call this Method It will give Different Result
Why-->Consider a Scenario where you are creating new resources
       Each time you call this method it will resulting in creating new resources Giving you the different result each time and hence ,POST(in simple word "Insert") is non idempotent method.

2>Other will Give you the Same result

Comment: Idempotency is not related to Response from a HTTP method,Please check the accepted answer on this post.

Comment: @NageshTripathi There was nothing mentioned about the response to a request, only about the result on the server (or rather the affected resources/entities), which correctly identifies idempotency. They even gave an analogy in math which describes the mode of operation pretty well.

Answer (score -12):

Idenpotent methods (GET,OPTIONS) don't change anything at the server (other than possibly adding log entries). Non-idempotent (PUT,POST,DELETE) methods change the data which is used to populate content in the web pages or effect change elsewhere (such as moving a crane, transferring funds, sending an email).

Comment: That's not entirely correct. Idempotent means that you can repeat the request and the result should be the same. PUT and DELETE fall in that category too.

Comment: What you described here is exactly the definition of "safe method" in HTTP specs. Idempotent methods are a superset of safe methods (All safe + PUT and DELETE)