# Does Django cache a POST request (and it's parameters)?

Tags: python, django, http, post, caching

I have a DRF API that implements views that allow `GET` and `POST` calls:

```
@api_view([
    'GET',
    'POST',
])
@cache_page(timeout=60 * 10)
def my_view(request):
  # do stuff
```

I noticed that:

1. `GET` requests get cached as expected.
2. `POST` requests do NOT get cached at all.

Questions:

1. Is this intended or am I doing something wrong?
2. If this is working as intended...how can I get Django to cache `POST` requests as well?

Comment: I can't understand why you would want this. A POST is meant to update something in the database. It wouldn't make sense to cache that.

Comment: POST is also used for purposes like `create a search db query` which is a read-only operation. In this case, each POST operation is idempotent and can benefit from caching.

Comment: No, it should not be. That should be a GET.

Comment: Not really. It depends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of the class in Django’s source code:

> More details about how the caching works:
>   * Only GET or HEAD-requests with status code 200 are cached.
>    Link: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/cache.py

The reason for this limitation is probably because GET requests are expected to be idempotent and POST requests are not, therefore it normally doesn’t make sense to cache POST requests.
Here is a question that explains this concept nicely: [What is idempotency in HTTP methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016234/what-is-idempotency-in-http-methods)

Django is open-source so you can always extend the cache mechanism to get this behavior, but it will probably confuse your API users as they will expect the POST to always be a new request.