# When designing Restful API, should I use DELETE or POST for UNFOLLOW?

Tags: rest, api, api-design, restful-url

I have this question in my mind for a day, I tried to do some reading from RESTful Web Services Cookbook and other stackoverflow posts, but still did not get a convincing answer to this question:

Assuming I have a database table storing relationships between two users, the relation represents that if user A is following user B (e.g. on Instagram/Twitter).

```
userId|userId
------|------
userA | userB
userA | userC
....
```

So now if user A would like to **unfollow** user B, then should this API be `DELETE` or `POST`?

In RESTful Web Services Cookbook page 11, it says:

*"The `DELETE` method is idempotent. This implies that the server must return response code 200 (OK) even if the server deleted the resource in a previous request. But in practice, implementing `DELETE` as an idempotent operation requires the server to keep track of all deleted resources. Otherwise, it can return a **404** (Not Found)."*

Does this suggest us to not use `DELETE` whenever we can avoid?

Thanks for any insight on this question!

Answer (score 3):

`DELETE` is for deleting specific resources. So if `DELETE` is appropriate for you depends on if you have a single resource that 'represents' the follow relationship between two users.

For example, if you have a resource as such:

```
/api/userA/follows/userB
```

Then it could be said that this resource represents the relationship between the two. It has a unique url, so this url can be deleted at which point I would expect the relationship to be severed.

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of [Evert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58158551/1426227), the `DELETE` method is suitable for your needs, as long as you have a resource that represents the relationship between two users.

The semantic of the `DELETE` method is defined in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**4.3.5.  DELETE**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)
>
> The `DELETE` method requests that the origin server remove the association between the target resource and its current functionality. [...]

The `DELETE` method is, in fact, meant to be idempotent, but your quote is *fundamentally wrong* when it relates idempotency with the status code.

As I previously mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019073/1426227), idempotency is not related to the status code itself. Idempotency is about the *effect* produced on *the state of the resource* on the server, even if the response for the subsequent requests are different from the first request.

Consider a client performs a `DELETE` request to delete a resource from the server. The server processes the request, the resource gets deleted and the server returns `204`. Then the client repeats the same `DELETE` request and, as the resource has already been deleted, the server returns `404` and that's totally fine.

Despite the different status code received by the client, the *effect* produced by a single `DELETE` request is the same effect of multiple `DELETE` requests to the same URI.