# ASP.NET Core Model Binding to force the prefix on complex types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-binding

Given a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {
    }

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller action:

`public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(MyModel myModel) {}`

how to achieve model binding behavior such that this binds properly:

```
www.host.blah/page?MyModel.Prop1=a&MyModel.Prop2=b
```

and this doesn't bind (without a prefix):

```
www.host.blah/page?Prop1=a&Prop2=b
```

I'm not sure of the correct terminology, but judging from [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#complex-types-1):

> For each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the
>   sources for the name pattern prefix.property_name. If nothing is
>   found, it looks for just property_name without the prefix.

but I want to avoid that default fallback without the prefix.

If it's relevant at all, I'm trying to accomplish this since the controller in question can be embedded in other controllers/pages, as a sub-tab in UI, so I can't control which other query string parameters will exist at that point.

Comment: why not use POST and avoid the querystring?

Comment: because of idempotency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016234/what-is-idempotency-in-http-methods

Comment: @MladenB. why do you care about *that* type of idempotency? And why expose message details in the resource model? What if you decide to rename that type, should you break the HTTP API as well?

Comment: `can be embedded in other controllers/pages,` that's not how controllers are meant to work. Controllers aren't just classes or modules, they *specify the API*. They aren't pages either, *views* are the pages.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I appreciate the concern but it feels like the conversation is diverging from the question, making it difficult for other people to stay focused on the point. I'll try to answer, but please try to stay focused on the original question, since that's the point where I need help with. Renaming is not an issue, since that can be addressed with the simple usage of `nameof`. The code has already been written that way and I don't have time to refactor the entire application, just to be able to solve a binding issue...

Answer (score 1):

Try the `OnPageHandlerSelected` method to manipulate the query string that executes before the model is selected.  You can register it globally and use it across the app.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;

public override void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
{
    //...
    var querystring = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value);
    var items = querystring.SelectMany(x => x.Value, (col, value) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(col.Key, value)).ToList();
}
```

Alternatively, you can create your own model binder

**Further Reading**:

- [Filters in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters)
- [Filter methods for Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
- [Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1)