# JHipster - Insert in the database with the GET method

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have to create an application with Jhipster but i never use it before.
When a user send a GET request to the address http://localhost:8080/api/newmesure/{mac-address}/{value}
I want to insert a new mesure in my database.

First i created 3 entity "Plantes", "Capteurs" and "Mesures" with this format :

Image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJqia.png (I'm not allowed to post)

I activated the JPA Filtering to create a @Query to insert data in my database but i read that was not possible.

In /src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/web/rest/MesuresRessources.java :

```
/**
 * REST controller for managing {@link com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Mesures}.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MesuresResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MesuresResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "mesures";

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    private final MesuresService mesuresService;

    private final MesuresQueryService mesuresQueryService;

    public MesuresResource(MesuresService mesuresService, MesuresQueryService mesuresQueryService) {
        this.mesuresService = mesuresService;
        this.mesuresQueryService = mesuresQueryService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/newMesure/{mac}/{value}")
    public String newMesure(@PathVariable String mac,@PathVariable int value) {

      log.debug("Adresse MAC : "+mac);
      log.debug("Valeur : "+value);

      @Query("SELECT valeur FROM Mesures WHERE id = 1") //not working
      Mesures getValeur(); //not working

      return "Mesure ajoutée";

    }
}
```

In /src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/domain/Mesures.java :

```
/**
 * A Mesures.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "mesures")
public class Mesures implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "valeur")
    private Integer valeur;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("macs")
    private Capteurs mac;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getValeur() {
        return valeur;
    }

    public Mesures valeur(Integer valeur) {
        this.valeur = valeur;
        return this;
    }

    public void setValeur(Integer valeur) {
        this.valeur = valeur;
    }

    public Capteurs getMac() {
        return mac;
    }

    public Mesures mac(Capteurs capteurs) {
        this.mac = capteurs;
        return this;
    }

    public void setMac(Capteurs capteurs) {
        this.mac = capteurs;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Mesures)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((Mesures) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mesures{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", valeur=" + getValeur() +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Louan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning java with JHipster is probably not a wise idea, it uses a very rich technology stack which might lose you unless you invest enough time to learn the basics.

There are many things wrong in your code and approach:

- You can't use `@Query` annotation inside the body of method a of your REST controller, it must be used in your `@Repository` interface, this code can't compile. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query for a quick introduction
- JPA filtering is not related to inserting into database
- In HTTP/REST, GET method is supposed to be idempotent. For making changes in your database you should use POST or PUT methods. See [What is idempotency in HTTP methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016234/what-is-idempotency-in-http-methods)
- Your entity naming convention is not consistent: use singular for entity classes because each entity object represents one single instance of Mesure. Here you have `Plantes` (plural), `Capteur` (singular) and `Mesures` (plural). For table names, JHipster uses singular but plural is quite common too because a table holds many rows. Of course, this is just a convention and you or your team may decide to apply another (like a prefix for table names) but the key point is to be consistent.

Comment: I know that learning java with Jhipster it's not a good approach but I have no choice.
Thanks for this post it will be usefull to help me in this project.
I will try to learn more about Spring.