# Is duduping same as idempotency

Tags: rest, terminology

It's clear for me what idempotence means based on this [Defining Idempotence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505889/defining-idempotence)

But I also heard a lot people describe such behavior as deduping. Is that an equivalent terminology?

For example, if an API is idempotent that same request being processed for N times will get the state same as one time. Can I say that API is deduping requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two terms are not equivalent, though it may be helpful for people unfamiliar with idempotency to think of it initially based on its similarity to deduplication.

For a contrasting example, consider an API for a bank account which accepts a positive or negative number by which to adjust the account balance (deposit or withdrawal). Clearly this API is not idempotent, because consecutive transactions have a cumulative effect.

On the other hand, we would certainly want to deduplicate these transactions. If transaction *#123* is (erroneously) submitted twice, it should apply to the account balance only once. In this case, transactions should be deduplicated *because* the API is *not* idempotent.

Deduplication is an activity: an action to perform. Idempotency is an attribute: a property to describe. A similarity exists between the two when the result of deduplication is the same as the effect of idempotency; that is, no change in state. But an equivalent outcome does not make the two terms equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I really love the last part "Deduplication is an activity: an action to perform. Idempotency is an attribute: a property to describe."

Now I am wondering, can I say deduplication is a method of implementing idempotency? In your example, we could add a "requestID" field in the API and let the API become idempotency so that transaction#123 submitted with the same requestID twice will not change the final state.

Comment: No, while deduplication can be a method of preventing state change, it can also be a method of causing state change (e.g. deduplicating a List). The latter has nothing to do with idempotency. And idempotency does not prevent anything. It describes an effect. Preventing a method from executing is not the same as executing it twice with the same effect.